# Task , given matrices, it is necessary to make the matrices "F" and "G" according to the scheme

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, mobius-inversion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UspCt.png)

( 2 ); B = (-2); C = (-1); D = = G₁ Task 3. Given matrices A = C= 1): D = (-2 1 2). 1) according to the schemes, make a mat

matrices F and G. Find the products of matrices F.G and G.F.2) Compile the matrix according to the scheme 2. Find the inverse matrix, check the result by the definition of the inverse matrix 3) For odd options: find the matrix
in the image follow link you can to see scheme

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Aside from not providing context or effort, your entire question is incomprehensible....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is so laid back as to be horizontal.